# Proving a matrix is semipositive definite

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-definite

Let $n \ge 2$, $\lambda_i>0$, $i=1,2,\cdots, n$. Let $\Lambda=\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i$. Let $$a_{ij}=\begin{cases}\frac{\Lambda}{\lambda_i}-1\quad &i=j\\
1\quad &i\ne j\end{cases}$$
My question is that, is $(a_{ij})$ a semipositive definite matrix?

I know that when $n=2$, each $a_{ii}$ is positive, and the determinant is $$(\frac{\Lambda}{\lambda_1}-1)(\frac{\Lambda}{\lambda_2}-1)-1=\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1}\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_2}-1=0.$$Hence $(a_{ij})$ is semipositive definite for $n=2$. How to show the matrix is also semipositive definite for any $n \ge 3$? Even for $n=3$, the computation is very complicated. I'm wondering if there is a neat way of seeing this, since the matrix is highly symmetric.

Comment: It's actual PD for $n\geq 3$.  The proof I came up with ends up looking like an analysis proof and uses tools from majorization so I'm not sure it will make sense.  What's the background motivation for this question?

Comment: @user8675309, sorry for taking your time to do this exercise. Actually the original question is let $a_{ij}=2\frac{\Lambda}{\lambda_i}-1$ when $i=j$, and $a_{ij}=-1$ when $i\ne j$. Then show that $a_{ij}$ is semi positive definite.  This is more doable, even though I also don't know how to prove for $n\ge 4$. Then I changed the question a little bit, which becomes the question posted. The question comes from a professor. He often gave us some problems to discuss.

Comment: Well I'll post the proof I have.  It is unfortunately a bit involved.  Perhaps someone else will come up with a more direct way of bounding $\text{trace}\big(D^{-1}\big)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume we have the usual ordering $\lambda_1\geq \lambda_2 \geq .... \geq \lambda_n \gt 0$.  Since $n=2$ **is already dealt with I only consider** $n\geq 3$ below.  And for $n\geq 3$ it is actually true that $A \succ \mathbf 0$.

$A= D + \mathbf {11}^T$
(where $\mathbf 1$ is a ones vector so $\mathbf {11}^T$ is the ones matrix sometimes denoted $J$ i.e. an outer product of two ones vectors)

Note that $A$ is a positive matrix (in the Perron Theory sense).

Then we have Diagonal matrix $D$ with diagonals
$d_{i,i} = \dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^n \lambda_k}{\lambda_i}-2$

**note 1:**
$d_{i,i}\leq 0\implies \sum_{k=1}^n \lambda_k\leq 2\lambda_i$
This is certainly possible for $\lambda_1$ but impossible for $j\neq 1$ because
$\sum_{k=1}^n \lambda_k \gt \lambda_1 + \lambda_2 \geq\lambda_1+\lambda_j\geq 2 \lambda_j$
(note in the disallowed $j=1$ case the middle inequality can break)

**note 2:**
this implies the ordering either
(i)  $0\leq d_{1,1,}\leq d_{2,2}\leq ... \leq d_{n,n}$  or
(ii)  $d_{1,1,}\lt 0\lt d_{2,2}\leq ... \leq d_{n,n}$

In case (i) we are basically done since a PSD matrix plus a PSD matrix is PSD. If $d_{1,1}\gt 0$ then it's a PD matrix plus PSD hence PD.  If $d_{1,1}=0$:
$\mathbf x \in \ker \big(D + \mathbf {11}^T\big)\implies D \mathbf x \propto \mathbf 1\implies \mathbf x \in \ker D$ (since $D$ kills the top coordinate of any vector hence its image is uniform iff zero)$\implies \mathbf x \propto \mathbf e_1$ but the first std basis vector isn't in the kernel of the ones matrix $\implies \mathbf x=\mathbf 0$, so the above matrix is PSD and invertible i.e. PD.

**The remainder of the post only considers Case (ii)**.
The eigenvalues of $A$ *interlace* those of $D$ so this means $A$ has at most one eigenvalue $\leq 0$.  Thus we will prove $A$ is PD by showing it has a positive determinant.  There may be a more direct approach but one way or another we want to estimate $\text{trace}\big(D^{-1}\big)$

**Now fix arbitrary** (a) $\lambda_1$ and (b) $c:= \sum_{k=1}^n \lambda_k$

the mapping $x\mapsto \frac{x}{c-2x}$  (i.e. $\lambda_i\mapsto d_{i,i}^{-1}$) has second derivative $\frac{4c}{(c-2x)^3}$ which is $\gt 0$ for $x \in S =\{\lambda_2, \lambda_3,...,\lambda_n\}$ for any allowable set $S$. Hence we get a strictly Schur convex function with respect to eigenvalues 2 through n.

Thus for reasons of strict Schur convexity we have
$\text{trace}\big(D^{-1}\big)$ is minimized when $\lambda_2=\lambda_3=...=\lambda_n$  and it is 'maximized' when $\lambda_2 \approx c - \lambda_1$.  I.e. when $\lambda_j\approx 0$ for $3\leq j\leq n$. We can exploit this in a more precise way sequentially.

With $\delta_r := 2^{-r}$ (starting with large enough $r$ to make the argument sensible)
$\lambda_{2_r} := c - \lambda_1 - \delta_r$
and $\lambda_{j_r} :=\frac{\delta_r}{n-2}$ for $3\leq j\leq n$

Then consider
$\text{trace}\big(D_r^{-1}\big) = \frac{\lambda_1}{c-2\lambda_1} + \frac{\lambda_{2_r}}{c-2\lambda_{2_r}}+(n-2)\frac{\delta_r}{n-2}\frac{1}{c - 2\frac{\delta_r}{n-2}}$
$=\frac{\lambda_1}{c-2\lambda_1} + \frac{\lambda_{2_r}}{c-2\lambda_{2_r}}+(\delta_r)\frac{1}{c - 2\frac{\delta_r}{n-2}}=\frac{\lambda_1}{c-2\lambda_1}+ \frac{\lambda_{2_r}}{c-2\lambda_{2_r}} + \epsilon_r$

to show the final term  $\epsilon_r \to 0$, look at the inverse
$(\delta_r)^{-1}\big(c - 2\frac{\delta_r}{n-2}\big)$, the second term is increasing in $r$ but bounded above by $c$ while the first term $\to \infty$ hence the product $\to \infty$ and the original (inverse) $\to 0$

So we have a strictly monotone increasing sequence
$s_r = \frac{\lambda_1}{c-2\lambda_1} + \frac{\lambda_{2_r}}{c-2\lambda_{2_r}}+\epsilon_r$
(justification for monotone behavior: combining majorization with strict Schur convexity)

$\lim_{r\to \infty}s_r = \frac{\lambda_1}{c-2\lambda_1} + \frac{c-\lambda_1}{c-2 (c-\lambda_1)}=-1$
We already know the RHS is $-1$ because OP already in effect proved that in the $2\times 2$ case.  I.e. using that result in combination with the matrix determinant lemma tells us
$0=\det\big(D_{2\times 2} +\mathbf 1_2\mathbf 1_2^T\big) = \det\big(D_{2\times 2} \big)\cdot\big(1+\mathbf 1_2^T D_{2\times 2}^{-1}\mathbf 1_2\big)= \det\big(D_{2\times 2} \big)\cdot \Big(1 + \text{trace}\big(D_{2\times 2}^{-1} \big)\Big)$
$\implies \frac{\lambda_1}{c-2\lambda_1} + \frac{c-\lambda_1}{c-2 (c-\lambda_1)}= \text{trace}\big(D_{2\times 2}^{-1}\big) =-1$
by selecting $D_{2\times 2}$ based off of eigenvalues $\lambda_1'=\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2':=c-\lambda_1$

side note: we know $\det\big(D_{2\times 2} \big) \neq 0$ because $0 \gt d^{(2\times 2)}_{1,1}$ and the only way the second component is 0 is if $\frac{\lambda_1'+\lambda_2'}{\lambda_2'}-2=0\implies \lambda_1'=\lambda_2'$  but then $0\gt d^{(2\times 2)}_{1,1} = d^{(2\times 2)}_{2,2}=0$ which is impossible)

Again fixing $\lambda_1$ and $c$ any given allowable choice of $D$ is majorized by $D_r$ for $r$ large enough so the argument is that $\text{trace}\big(D^{-1}\big) \leq \text{trace}\big(D_r^{-1}\big) = s_r \lt \lim_{r\to \infty}s_r= -1$.

Finally applying matrix determinant lemma to the problem we get
$\det\big(A\big) =\det\big(D +\mathbf {11}^T\big)  = \det\Big(D\Big)\cdot \Big(1+\mathbf 1^TD^{-1}\mathbf 1\Big)= \det\big(D\big)\cdot \Big(1+ \text{trace}\big(D^{-1}\big)\Big)\gt 0$
i.e. both terms are negative so their product is positive and $A$ must have all positive eigenvalues.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I know that showing a matrix is PSD can be so difficult...